# Why does JSP show only one single employee details not all?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm displaying the details of employee stored in the database
and my servlet code creates an Arraylist of employee objects and sends it to JSP through `RequestDispatcher` forward method.
I have set an attribute in `request.setAttribute("emp", list)` which takes that list as parameter.

```
request.setAttribute("emp", list);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/rafi.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

And my JSP file uses JSTL to display details of employees from that list
code goes like this:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${emp}" var="employ">
        <tr>
            <td>${employ.id}</td>
            <td>${employ.username}</td>
            <td>${employ.password}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

But I'm only getting one employee details instead of all employee details for example if employees are abc and xyz the output is abc abc. How should I fix this?

Comment: can you provide the detail of list you are sending from servlet ?

Comment: You should fix the code that creates the list and create a new item for each employee rather than re-using the same object.

Comment: Ok thank you so much i did that mistake i haven't created object for each employee and when i fix it i got the proper result.Thanks a lot!!